# Factory function to create a class with an unknown number of mixins

Tags: python, factory, mixins

I am wanting to make a function that creates a new class from a variable amount of so-called mixin classes. My first instinct is to use `*args` ...

```
>>> def mixins(*args):
        class Foo(*args):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

... but didn't get very far ... Since that didn't work, I tried this, which seems to work:

```
>>> def mixins(*args):
        class Foo(args[0]):
            pass
        for arg in args[1:]:
            class Foo(Foo, arg):
                pass
        return Foo
```

#### Question

Are there other approaches to solving this problem?

#### Motivation

I have created an Abstract Base Class that has many abstract methods. I have several types of subclasses, which each implement some of the needed abstract methods but not all of them. Sometimes I can create a working instance by mixing in 2 subclasses, sometimes it takes more to implement all of the abstract methods.

Comment: My instinct tells me there must be a better approach.  Can you explain  exactly what the motivation of doing that? Perhaps using class-decorators would be more suitable.  Does your problem require an inheritance-based solution?

Comment: @shx2 I have added text about the motivation for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function:

```
def mixins(*args):
    return type('Foo', args, {})
```

You might also want to make sure that the class always inherits from `object`:

```
def mixins(*args):
    bases = args if object in args else args + (object,)
    return type('Foo', bases, {})
```

Comment: Excellent! I remember reading about the `type` function recently in this excellent (and long) answer for [What is a metaclass in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/1988505).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Why not?

Here is how you can make class objects on the fly:

`type('a',(object,),{})`

This will create a class object of type - type and which derives from the object base class and whose attributes are an empty dictionary.

So, in your case,the call would be:

`type('Foo',args,{})`

Here, args will be contain all the base classes you want to inherit Foo from. and the resultant would be a clas object which you can use to return from mixins.